MariaDB Json: Get every key of the whole JSON-column
CREATE TABLE t (j LONGTEXT);

INSERT INTO t (j) VALUES ('{"a":"1"}');

INSERT INTO t (j) VALUES ('{"b":"2"}');

INSERT INTO t (j) VALUES ('{"c":"0", "d":"0"}');

INSERT INTO t (j) VALUES ('{"c":"1", "d":"1"}');

SELECT JSON_KEYS(j) FROM t;
+--------------+
| JSON_KEYS(j) |
+--------------+
| ["a"]        |
| ["b"]        |
| ["c", "d"]   |
| ["c", "d"]   |
+--------------+

I am looking for a list of every keys in the whole table? Is that possible?
Such as
+----------------------+
| ["a", "b", "c", "d"] |
+----------------------+

r even better.
+-----+
| "a" |
| "b" |
| "c" |
| "d" |
+-----+


You can use JSON_TABLE() along with JSON_KEYS() for version 10.6+ :
SELECT DISTINCT jt.*
FROM t, 
     JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(j), '$[*]' 
       COLUMNS (
                 labelKey VARCHAR(40) PATH '$'
               )
     ) jt

Demo

I know people seem to like using comma joins with JSON_TABLE, but when you need to join other tables too it leads to the usual problems with mixing comma joins and sql standard joins.  better to do FROM t CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE...

Depending on what you want, one of:
# just the values
select distinct k
from t
cross join
json_table(json_keys(j), '$[*]' columns (k text path '$')) j
order by k

or
# quoted values
select distinct json_quote(k)
from t
cross join
json_table(json_keys(j), '$[*]' columns (k text path '$')) j
order by k

or
# in an array
select json_arrayagg(distinct k order by k)
from t
cross join
json_table(json_keys(j), '$[*]' columns (k text path '$')) j


This can be done using JSON_TABLE as follows :
SELECT DISTINCT `Key`
FROM t, 
     JSON_TABLE(
         JSON_KEYS(t.j),
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS(
           `Key` VARCHAR(10) PATH "$"
         )
      ) d

Demo here
